# Adding a column from another dataframe to existing dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a PySpark dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

Also suppose have another dataframe `df_new` with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
```

What is the easiest way of adding the `city` column from `df_new` to `df`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `df.insert()` to add a new column

```py
df.insert(2,"city",df_new["city"])
```

given the information you provided this should suffice

Comment: This is a Pyspark dataframe

Comment: once again this might depend on your data.
pyspark provides `df.join()` and `df.withColumn()` functions